# Publishing error in Deployment committing phase

Tags: 2011, publishing

I am getting following error in publishing log of a file.

> Phase: Deployment Prepare Commit Phase failed, Unable to prepare transaction: tcm:0-25741-66560, Attempting to deploy a binary 40040 to a location where a different binary is already stored Existing binary: 38858:,

Comment: You could take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12458609/attempting-to-deploy-a-binary-to-a-location-where-a-different-binary-is-already
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14856708/attempting-to-deploy-a-binary-to-a-location-where-a-different-binary-is-already

Comment: And this one as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14856708/attempting-to-deploy-a-binary-to-a-location-where-a-different-binary-is-already

Comment: Its is bit difficult to find out duplicates, I have looked into logs and found only 1 component with 1 image, "Adding binary" step adds only 1 binary and image name is different from component name. Is there any way to inspect the package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you've already got a binary (image, pdf etc) located in your website with the same file name.

To help you explain the problem, there's also some great content online:

http://www.urbancherry.net/blogengine/post/2010/02/09/Unique-binary-filenames-for-SDL-Tridion-Multimedia-Components.aspx

There's also a tridion power tool that can help you identify where your publication contains duplicate binaries:

https://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-power-tools/wiki/DuplicateBinaries

Comment: I have power tools installed but I can't see all tolls on my ribbon, I can see only "Image uploaded", "Page publisher", "Count items", "Application data inspector" and "Power tools help"

Comment: The tool is shown when right clicking a publication item only - thanks

Comment: I could not see any file duplication in my package but adding a TBB that makes sure all files have unique name solved the issue.

Comment: Forcing unique binary names usually masks the root cause of the problem and facilitates redundant data to be uploaded into the CMS. I have described the scenario in more detail here: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/9584/159