# PublishBinaries fails on a specific Target

Tags: 2011, publishing

We have a TBB created to Publish Binaries files based on [this post.](http://www.urbancherry.net/blogengine/post/2010/02/09/Unique-binary-filenames-for-SDL-Tridion-Multimedia-Components.aspx)

Multiple instances of this TBB is used in a web site to publish Images, CSS and JS files from different folders. It TBB works fine in Template Builder without any issues. It does work well on couple of Targets.

Unfortunately, publishing fails on a specific target while committing the transaction with the following error message.

> Committing Deployment Failed:
>
> Phase: Deployment Prepare Commit Phase failed, Unable to prepare transaction: tcm:0-91781-66560, Attempting to deploy a binary 29967 to a location where a different binary is already stored Existing binary: 977:, Attempting to deploy a binary 29967 to a location where a different binary is already stored Existing binary: 977:, Unable to prepare transaction: tcm:0-91781-66560, Attempting to deploy a binary 29967 to a location where a different binary is already stored Existing binary: 977:, Attempting to deploy a binary 29967 to a location where a different binary is already stored Existing binary: 977:

This happens only when publishing using Publish Binaries (Images & JS files). Images created as components are published without any problem.

To resolve this problem we have deleted the target directory and republished the pages. Still the problem continues just for these pages alone.

Can someone help with what could be the general issues to cause the commit to fail?

Thanks,

Anbu

**Updated: 2014-02-15** Most of the replies are pointing to the duplicate file on the file system folder and/or images components. I agree, they should be unique. I'm able to publish the same binaries on other targets, but only to the specific target. If the files are not unique, publishing should have failed on all targets. Please note, we have deleted the entire binaries folder to ensure no files are exist under the target folder.

Comment: The easy fix is likely renaming the conflicting uploaded image(s). See answers for other approaches. Find the image using the Content Manager's search by entering the full tcm id.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error message is explaining that one binary (29967) cannot be deployed because another binary (977) has already been deployed with an identical filename. The deployer will not allow you to overwrite one binary with another.

You can find these components in Tridion by locating `tcm:<publication-ID>-29967` and `tcm:<publication-ID>-977` (try searching for them in the Content Manager Explorer).

I suspect you will find that both components have been uploaded with the same filename and that your TBB to ensure filename uniqueness is not working in this instance (perhaps because it is not configured for your template, it is not working correctly or it is not working in the way that you think).

Answer (score 9):

This error seems to be quite common to newer Tridion devs, so it has been covered already in quite detail. Basically what happens is that you have already published another Multimedia Component to the same presentation folder under the same file name.

Please check the resources below:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12458609/attempting-to-deploy-a-binary-to-a-location-where-a-different-binary-is-already
- http://yatb.mitza.net/2012/03/publishing-images-as-variants.html#!/2012/03/publishing-images-as-variants.html
- http://www.urbancherry.net/blogengine/post/2010/02/09/Unique-binary-filenames-for-SDL-Tridion-Multimedia-Components.aspx

Comment: Hi Mihai, I've looked into these article. But unable fix the issue as it happens only on the specific target and not on all targets from the same publisher.  Could it be due to certain permission issue or configuration on the server end?

Comment: THis is not a permission or configuration thing. On that particular target, you have two binaries (id 29967 and 977) with the same filename in the same directoy and you are trying to deploy binary 29967 on top of 977. This is not allowed. You'll need to fix the naming convention of these binaries to make them unique per folder. Try unpublishing binary 977 by unpublishing all pages that make references to it.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at these answers:

[Publishing error in Deployment committing phase](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/4135/publishing-error-in-deployment-committing-phase)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14856708/attempting-to-deploy-a-binary-to-a-location-where-a-different-binary-is-already

http://www.urbancherry.net/blogengine/post/2010/02/09/Unique-binary-filenames-for-SDL-Tridion-Multimedia-Components.aspx

Comment: hahaha... copy cats :)

Comment: No point answering it again right :)